# Rails: using before_actions as 'or' conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller

In this situation, users can satisfy four non-overlapping conditions: A, B, C, and/or D.

- Before `#show`, users should be redirected unless they satisfy conditions A, B, or C.
- Before `#edit`, `#update`, and `#destroy`, users should be redirected unless they satisfy conditions B or C.
- Before `#index`, users should be redirected unless they satisfy condition C.

Given those conditions, is there a simpler, more effective, or more Rails-y way to write `before_action`s for the `UsersController` than the code below?

```
before_action :a_through_c, only: [:show]
before_action :b_through_c, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :c,           only: [:index]
...

private

def a_through_c
  b_through_c unless current_user.satisfies_condition?(a)
end

def b_through_c
  c unless current_user.satisfies_condition?(b)
end

def c
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.satisfies_condition?(c)
end
```

Just so you know, I'm not looking for the code below -- only B or C should allow `#edit`, `#update`, and `#destroy` to pass, and only C should allow `#index` to pass. The code below allows A, B, or C to pass any of the actions.

```
before_action :accessible, only: [:show, :index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
...
private

def accessible
  unless
    current_user.satisfies_condition?(a) ||
    current_user.satisfies_condition?(b) ||
    current_user.satisfies_condition?(c)
    redirect_to(root_url)
  end
end
```

Comment: I would define separate methods for A, B and C and before actions for each required combination.  I'm not sure it is the most Railsy way but it should be transparent and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [steve klein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3311657/steve-klein)'s comment. I like this solution because of its transparency. I would definitely rework the `satisfies_condition` method to take a parameter array (for DRYness) if this weren't a hypothetical example.

```
before_action :a_or_b_or_c, only: [:show]
before_action :b_or_c, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :c, only: [:index]

...

private

def a_or_b_or_c
  unless
    current_user.satisfies_condition?(a) ||
    current_user.satisfies_condition?(b) ||
    current_user.satisfies_condition?(c)
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end

def b_or_c
  unless
    current_user.satisfies_condition?(b) ||
    current_user.satisfies_condition?(c) ||
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end

def c
  unless
    current_user.satisfies_condition?(c)
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```